# Slide up down animation in the react native

Tags: react-native, animation, react-animated, react-native-animatable

I am using animation for up and down in the react native, But the animation just slide from up to down and then stop at the bottom i want to move it up and down continuously. I have also used animation loop so please check and provide me solution for this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Animated, Easing, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import LoaderLogo from '../../icons/commonicons/LoaderLogo'
import { Loadericon } from '../../constants/Image';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import { dynamicSize } from '../sizechoose';

const amimationScreen = () => {
    const startValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    const endValue = dynamicSize(225);

    const startValue2 = new Animated.Value(225);
    const endValue2 = dynamicSize(0);
    const duration = 5000;

    useEffect(() => {

        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(startValue, {
                toValue: endValue,
                duration: duration,
                useNativeDriver: true,
            }),
            Animated.timing(startValue2, {
                toValue: endValue2,
                duration: duration,
                useNativeDriver: true,
            })
        ]).start()

    }, [startValue, endValue, duration]);

    return (
        <Animated.View style={[{ transform: [{ translateY: startValue }] }]}>
       <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',height:10,width:100}}>
            </View>
        </Animated.View>
    )
}


export default amimationScreen
```

I also tried with react-native-animatable package but it is not good to use for me as it starts animation from the top of the screen.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
const App = () => {
  const animated = new Animated.Value(0);
  const duration = 5000;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(animated, {
          toValue: 255,
          duration: duration,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(animated, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: duration,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      ]),
    ).start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[{transform: [{translateY: animated}]}]}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 10, width: 100}}></View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

So instead of having two instances of `Animated.Value` for translation, create one and let it transition from `0` to `255` and from `255` back to `0` in sequence. And make it loop once the sequence has finished.

---

I think the main problem in your original approach is that `startValue` decides how the view translates since this is what you pass as the value of `translateY`. The downward animation therefore happens correctly in your example. The upward animation however does not happen, because `startValue2` is passed to `Animated.timing` and `startValue` is not used in the translation of any views in your example.

Comment: great, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, Dimensions, Easing, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';


export const App = () => {
    const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const [isTop, setIsTop] = useState(true);

    const startAnimation = toValue => {
        Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
            toValue,
            duration: 1000,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start(() => {
            setIsTop(!isTop);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        startAnimation(isTop ? 1 : 0);
    }, [isTop]);

    const translateY = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, Dimensions.get('window').height - 70],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.square, { transform: [{ translateY }] }]}>

            </Animated.View>
        </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    square: {
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
});
```